# Redirect for PHP quiz form

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to set up my form that I got from https://css-tricks.com/building-a-simple-quiz/#comments so that if all answers are incorrect then it adds "Failed" to the results and a button to try again. However, if all answers are correct, then it displays "Pass" and a button to continue to a new page

While I admit I am no pro to coding and scripting, I tried just changing the echo with a link but that doesn't give a different display to each result I'm looking for. Pretty much they have to get all the answers correct to move forward or can try again.

Here is the code that I am using

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <title>PHP Quiz</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <div id="page-wrap">

        <h1>Final Quiz for Lip building</h1>

        <?php

            $answer1 = $_POST['question-1-answers'];
            $answer2 = $_POST['question-2-answers'];
            $answer3 = $_POST['question-3-answers'];
            $answer4 = $_POST['question-4-answers'];
            $answer5 = $_POST['question-5-answers'];

            $totalCorrect = 0;

            if ($answer1 == "B") { $totalCorrect++; }
            if ($answer2 == "A") { $totalCorrect++; }
            if ($answer3 == "C") { $totalCorrect++; }
            if ($answer4 == "D") { $totalCorrect++; }
            if ($answer5) { $totalCorrect++; }

            echo "<div id='results'>$totalCorrect / 5 correct</div>";

        ?>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-68528-29");
    pageTracker._initData();
    pageTracker._trackPageview();
    </script>

</body>

</html>

________
AND the PHP (grade.php) file
________


<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">



<?php

    $answer1 = $_POST['question-1-answers'];
    $answer2 = $_POST['question-2-answers'];
    $answer3 = $_POST['question-3-answers'];
    $answer4 = $_POST['question-4-answers'];
    $answer5 = $_POST['question-5-answers'];

    $totalCorrect = 0;

    if ($answer1 == "B") { $totalCorrect++; }
    if ($answer2 == "A") { $totalCorrect++; }
    if ($answer3 == "C") { $totalCorrect++; }
    if ($answer4 == "D") { $totalCorrect++; }
    if ($answer5) { $totalCorrect++; }

    echo "<div id='results'>$totalCorrect / 5 correct</div>";

?>





</body>
</html>
```

Not getting any errors as is

Comment: Is this the original code or the one you modified?

Comment: It's the original one because anything I tried to change just gave an error. Which means I'm clueless haha.

Comment: I figure once I can get the result right, then I can edit the questions and answers

Answer (score 0):

Simple if statement will do the trick

You can add this changes in grade.php under this line

```
 echo "<div id='results'>$totalCorrect / 5 correct</div>";
```

to check if the user pass the test or not by checking the mark he get

```
if($totalCorrect == 5){
    echo "<div id='results'>Pass</div>";
    echo '<button type="button" href="redirect.php">Click Me!</button>';

} else {
    echo "<div id='results'>Fail</div>";
}
```

Comment: AHHHHH Thank you so much! I am more grateful than I can say. I will try this after I clock out of work tonight. Thank you again!

Comment: This is excellent, however when I click on the button it doesn't go to the page. I edited redirect.php to register.html